# Uncaught Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, typescript, api

Uncaught Request failed with status code 400 at createError (node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15) at settle (node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12) at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:293:11) I am getting this error can anyone help me here

Its abruptly getting close for 400 response on digestAuth.request and on the other hand working fine for 200 responses.
On resolve(await response) storing the response either for 200 or 400

I am expecting that for 400 it should returns response and get stores into resolve(await response)

```
 public static lisCreate(payload): Promise<any> {
    const sendPostRequest = new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const digestAuth = new AxiosDigestAuth({
        username: Environment.labAdminUsername ,
        password: Environment.labadminLisPassword ,
      });
        const response = await digestAuth.request({
          headers: { Accept: 'application/json'
        },
          method: "POST",
          url: `${Environment.siteUrl}integration/orders/requests`,
          data: payload,
        });
      
        logger.info(`Payload is  :- ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
        logger.info(`API call to '${Environment.siteUrl}integration/orders/requests' returns with status '${response.status}'`);
        resolve(await response);
        
    });
    
    return sendPostRequest;
  }
}
```

Comment: By default, all responses which don't have status code 2xx will throw errors, see the [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors). Everything is working like expected.

Comment: I am here trying to save error response in the resolve(await response) which I am not able to do so

Comment: Your error is thrown at `await digestAuth.request()`, in case of 400 it doesn't even reach the `resolve()`. You might want to research on how to do error handling in async functions in general.